# chrome extension Manifest v3 background.service_worker .js file lifecycle

Tags: google-chrome-extension, page-lifecycle

```
"background": {
```

"service_worker": "background.js"
}enter code here

in "background.js" file variable, after a few minutes of window inactivity, variable value is reset, how to keep in "background.js" file variable value until window closed.